# How to clear AutoCompleteTextView with inputType = none

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components-android

I need a dropdown menu in my UI. Following the instructions I found on [material.io](https://material.io/components/menus/android#exposed-dropdown-menus) I used AutoCompleteTextView with `inputType="none"`. I need to reset it on button press and show the placeholder again, but if I use `setText("")` it will show an empty choice, I want to actually clear the AutoCompleteTextView and show the placeholder again. How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

In **java** :

```
 button.setOnClickListener(v->{
            autoCompleteTextView.setText(null);
            //autoCompleteTextView.setText("");// or you can use this
            autoCompleteTextView.setFocusable(false);
        });
```

And this for **Kotlin** :

```
button.setOnClickListener { v: View? ->
            autoCompleteTextView.setText(null)
            autoCompleteTextView.isFocusable = false
        }
```

Comment: it worked, thanks! Just to clarify, I don't understand why isFocusable = false is needed here. Can you please explain a bit more? The solution is working perfectly, anyway!

Comment: It is interesting that clearListSelection() is not working.